# Calling Nested Function In Javascript - Is Not Defined Error When Called Within jQuery.ajax.success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an ajax form submission inside an object.

When I try call the other object methods within the jQuery.ajax.success callback, this line throws an error...

Is this a scoping issue?

```
this.DisplayError(data.error);
```

this.DisplayError is not a function

Code:

```
    var toolsform = new function() {

        this.sumbitUrl = 'submit.php';


        this.DisplayError = function(errorMsg) {
            jQuery('#trialFormError').html('<strong>Error: </strong>' + errorMsg);  
        }

        this.AjaxSumbit = function() {

            let formData = jQuery("#trialsToolsRegisterForm").serialize();
            formData += '&toolsFormSumbit=1';

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: this.sumbitUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {

                    if(data.success === false) { 
                        this.DisplayError(data.error);
                    }

                    console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
                }
            }); 
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Turn `success` into an arrow function to preserve the `this` context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2):

Use arrow function:

```
success: () => {

}
```

This happens because you are loosing context, Ajax assigns different context when calling success function. You can also save context in New variable:

```
var self = this;
```

And use it inside success function instead of this.
Or you can define function context:

```
success: (function() {

}).bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the success function is not equal to `this` outside. The simplest way to handle this is using arrow function.

```
var toolsform = new function() {

    this.sumbitUrl = 'submit.php';


    this.DisplayError = function(errorMsg) {
        jQuery('#trialFormError').html('<strong>Error: </strong>' + errorMsg);  
    }

    this.AjaxSumbit = function() {

        let formData = jQuery("#trialsToolsRegisterForm").serialize();
        formData += '&toolsFormSumbit=1';

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: this.sumbitUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            success: data => {

                if(data.success === false) { 
                    this.DisplayError(data.error); // now `this` should be equal to the one outside
                }

                console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        }); 
    }   
}
```

The magic is, arrow function does not has its own `this`. When you call `this`, it will refer to the outside one. But normal function has its own `this`, therefore when you call `this`, it will refer to its own `this` instead of the outside one.

For details, you may take a look on the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks very much. I knew it was some kind of scoping issue.